# Excel Place Values Cumulation in Table by Date and Category

Tags: microsoft-excel

Excel. How to place in table a cumulation of values by date and category? The excel sheet is downloadable via the following wetransfer-link: https://we.tl/7LC1Mi4MqW
[image]

Comment: check the SUMIFS() function

Answer (score 0):

=SUMIFS($P:$P,$Q:$Q,$A4,$N:$N,B$2)

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explain why/how this solves the problem.  Thanks.